# Wrong result of a python program when use concurrently with other python programs using cron or subprocess but works fine when run individually

Tags: python, concurrency, cron, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am facing a weird problem.

First I would explain the purpose of my code.

Its a webscraping code in python which extracts information from the website and insert them into my local host.

The whole program is this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import MySQLdb
import re
import pdb
import sys





def getting_urls_of_all_pages(): 

    i=1
    while i<=40: #40 is the total number of main pages
        url_rent_flat='http://dubai.dubizzle.com/property-for-rent/residential/apartmentflat/?page='+str(i) #url of the main page (iterating to 40)

        
        link=[]
        htmlfile=urllib.urlopen(url_rent_flat).read()
        soup=BeautifulSoup(htmlfile)

        link=soup.find_all('a',xtclib=re.compile("listing_list_\d+_title_link"),href=True) #stores all the links (25) links of the page
    
        """
        Part 2: passing each property url to process for data extraction
        """
        
        for a in link:
            every_property_in_a_page_data_extraction(a['href']) 
        
        i+=1


def every_property_in_a_page_data_extraction(url):

    

    # global count_prop
    
    # count_curr=""
    # date_result=""
    title_result=""
    price_result=""
    bedroom_result="" 
    agencyfee_result="" 
    bathroom_result="" 
    size_result=""
    propertyref_result=""
    furnished_result=""
    rent_is_paid_result=""
    building_result=""
    Amenities_result=""
    tradename_result=""
    licencenum_result=""
    reraid_result=""
    phone_result=""
    link_result=""
    Zoned_for_result=""
    Freehold_result=""
    Pricepersq_result=""
    Type_result="Apartment"
    Sale_Rent_result="Rent"
    rows=0

    


    """
    Part1: Extracting data
    """
    
    htmlfile=urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(htmlfile)

    """
    Part2: Extracting the components
    """

    #date
    # try:
    #   date=soup.find("h3","listing-details-header") 
    #   date_result= str(date.get_text().encode("utf-8").strip()[20:])
    #   print "\nPublished date: ", date_result
    # except StandardError as e:
    #   phone_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
    #   print phone_result

    # Sale/Rent
    print "Sale/Rent: ", Sale_Rent_result

    # Type of property
    print "Type of property: ", Type_result

    #title
    try:
        title= soup.find('span',{'id':'listing-title-wrap'})
        title_result= str(title.get_text().strip().encode("utf-8"))
        print "Title: ",title_result
    except StandardError as e:
        title_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
        print title_result

    #price
    try:
        price = soup.find('span',{'id':'actualprice'})
        price_result= str(price.get_text())
        print "Price: ",price_result
    except StandardError as e:
        price_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
        print price_result

    #Agency Fee, Bedroom, Bathroom, Size
    spans_ABBS= []
    for a in soup.select(".important-fields li span"):
        spans_ABBS.append(a.text.strip())

    strongs_ABBS=[]
    for a in soup.select(".important-fields li strong"):
        strongs_ABBS.append(a.text.strip())

    
    for name, value in zip(spans_ABBS, strongs_ABBS):
        if name=="Agency Fees:":
            try:
                agencyfee_result= str(value)
                print "Agency Fees: ", agencyfee_result
            except StandardError as e:
                agencyfee_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print agencyfee_result

        elif name=="Bedrooms:":
            try:
                bedroom_result= str(value)
                print "Number of Bedrooms: ",bedroom_result
            except StandardError as e:
                bedroom_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print bedroom_result

        elif name=="Bathrooms:":
            try:
                bathroom_result= str(value)
                print "Number of Bathrooms: ", bathroom_result
            except StandardError as e:
                bathroom_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print bathroom_result

        elif name=="Size:":
            try:
                size_result= str(value)
                print "Size of the property: ",size_result
            except StandardError as e:
                size_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print size_result

        elif name=="Zoned For:":
            try:
                Zoned_for_result= str(value)
                print "Zoned For:",Zoned_for_result
            except StandardError as e:
                Zoned_for_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print Zoned_for_result

        elif name=="Freehold:":
            try:
                Freehold_result= str(value)
                print "Freehold: ",Freehold_result
            except StandardError as e:
                Freehold_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print Freehold_result

        elif name=="Price / SqFt:":
            try:
                Pricepersq_result= str(value)
                print "Price Per Sqft: ",Pricepersq_result
            except StandardError as e:
                Pricepersq_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print Pricepersq_result

    #Property Reference, Furnished, Listed By, Rent Is Paid, Building, Amenities: 
    spans_others=[]
    for a in soup.select("#listing-details-list li span"):
            spans_others.append(a.text.strip())

    strongs_others=[]
    for a in soup.select("#listing-details-list li strong"):
        strongs_others.append(a.text.strip())


    
    for name, value in zip(spans_others, strongs_others):
        if name=="Listed by:":
            break
        
        elif name=="Property Reference:":
            try:
                propertyref_result=str(value.strip())
                print "Property reference in Dubizel: ",propertyref_result
            except StandardError as e:
                propertyref_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print propertyref_result

        elif name=="Furnished:":
            try:
                furnished_result=str(value.strip())
                print "Furnished status: ",furnished_result
            except StandardError as e:
                furnished_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print furnished_result


        elif name=="Rent Is Paid:":
            try:
                rent_is_paid_result=str(value.strip())
                print "Rent payment: ",rent_is_paid_result
            except StandardError as e:
                rent_is_paid_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print rent_is_paid_result
    
        elif name=="Building:":
            try:
                building_result=str(value.strip())
                print "Building info: ",building_result
            except StandardError as e:
                building_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print building_result
        elif name=="Amenities:":
            try:
                for a in value.split(","):
                    Amenities_result+=a.strip()+","
                print Amenities_result
            except StandardError as e:
                Amenities_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print Amenities_result
            


    #Agents info --> TTrade Name, DED Licence Number, RERA Registration Number
    spans_broker=[]
    for a in soup.select("#broker-details li span"):
            spans_broker.append(a.text.strip())

    strongs_broker=[]
    for a in soup.select("#broker-details  li strong"):
        strongs_broker.append(a.text.strip())

    
    for name, value in zip(spans_broker, strongs_broker):
        if name=="Trade Name:":
            try:
                tradename_result=str(value.strip())
                print "Trade name: ",tradename_result
            except StandardError as e:
                tradename_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print tradename_result

        elif name=="DED Licence Number:":
            try:
                licencenum_result=str(value.strip())
                print "Licence #: ",licencenum_result
            except StandardError as e:
                licencenum_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print licencenum_result

        elif name=="RERA Registration Number:":
            try:
                reraid_result=str(value.strip())
                print "RERA ID #: ",reraid_result
            except StandardError as e:
                reraid_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
                print reraid_result


    # phone num
    try:
        phone=soup.find_all("div", "phone-content")
        for a in phone:
            phone_result= str(a.get_text().strip().encode("utf-8"))
        print "Phone information:", phone_result
    except StandardError as e:
        phone_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
        print phone_result

        

    #link
    try:
        link = soup.find('input',{'id':'short-link-input'})
        link_result= str(link.get('value'))
        print "Short Reference link: ", link_result
    except StandardError as e:
        link_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
        print link_result


    #double check of the types before conversion
    # print map(type, (date_result, Sale_Rent_result,Type_result, title_result, price_result, Pricepersq_result, bedroom_result, agencyfee_result, bathroom_result, size_result, propertyref_result, furnished_result, rent_is_paid_result, building_result, Amenities_result, tradename_result, licencenum_result, reraid_result, phone_result, link_result))



    
    # count_prop+=1

    """
    Connecting to Database and putting data into in
    """
    
    db= MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","ahmed","practice")
    cursor=db.cursor()

    #checking phase to stop scrapping
    sql = """SELECT Short_link FROM Properties WHERE Short_link=%s"""
    print rows
    rows = cursor.execute(sql,(link_result))
    print rows
    if rows>=1:
        print "Already present - The program is terminating"
        sys.exit()
    else:
        query="""INSERT INTO Properties (Sale_Rent, Type, Title,Price, PricePerSqrFt, Bedroom,Agency_Fee, Bathroom, Size,ZonedFor, Freehold, Prop_ref,Furnished_status,Rent_payment,Building_info,Amenities,Trade_name,Licence, RERA_ID,Phone_info,Short_link) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
        cursor.execute(query,(Sale_Rent_result,Type_result, title_result, price_result, Pricepersq_result, bedroom_result, agencyfee_result, bathroom_result, size_result,Zoned_for_result, Freehold_result, propertyref_result, furnished_result, rent_is_paid_result, building_result, Amenities_result, tradename_result, licencenum_result, reraid_result, phone_result, link_result))


    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
    


#-----------------------------------------------------------




# count_prop=1
getting_urls_of_all_pages()
```

At the end of the code, it checks the unique column of my database (which i am getting from the website) that if its there, the scraping stops (because i dont want to scrape the same data multiple times)

The part of the code which does this job is this

```
#checking phase to stop scrapping
        sql = """SELECT Short_link FROM Properties WHERE Short_link=%s"""
        print rows
        rows = cursor.execute(sql,(link_result))
        print rows
        if rows>=1:
            print "Already present - The program is terminating"
            sys.exit()
        else:
            query="""INSERT INTO Properties (Sale_Rent, Type, Title,Price, PricePerSqrFt, Bedroom,Agency_Fee, Bathroom, Size,ZonedFor, Freehold, Prop_ref,Furnished_status,Rent_payment,Building_info,Amenities,Trade_name,Licence, RERA_ID,Phone_info,Short_link) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
            cursor.execute(query,(Sale_Rent_result,Type_result, title_result, price_result, Pricepersq_result, bedroom_result, agencyfee_result, bathroom_result, size_result,Zoned_for_result, Freehold_result, propertyref_result, furnished_result, rent_is_paid_result, building_result, Amenities_result, tradename_result, licencenum_result, reraid_result, phone_result, link_result))
```

Now, I have 3 different python programs which does the same extraction for 3 different websites. I have to run these 3 programs at the same time named AppFlatForRent.py, AppFlatForRent.py, AppFlatForRent.py

***Problem***

When i run these 3 programs individually, they run perfectly but when i try to run the programs using cron or python subprocess.Popen method, one of the 3 programs returns 1 in the `row` variable even when the database is empty-  which terminates the program from the start.

I dont know why whenever i try to run these programs concurrently, the row variable becomes 1 and skips one of the 3 programs

*** Methods i am trying for concurrency***

1. This runs 13 programs concurrently with skipping the AppFlatForRent.py because of returning 1 in the row variable and terminating the program.

   import subprocess
   import os

   ```
   scripts_to_run = ['CommercialForSale.py','AppFlatForRent.py','AppForSale.py','MultipleUnitsForSale.py','RentalWanted.py','RentCommercial.py','RoomsForRent.py','RoomsWanted.py','ShortTermDaily.py','VillaHouseForRent.py', 'LandForSale.py','ShortTermMonthly.py','VillaHouseForSale.py']



   for s in scripts_to_run:
       subprocess.Popen(["python", os.path.join(os.getcwd(), s)])
   ```
2. Cron tab- It also ignores one program AppFlatForRent.py after returning row variable to 1 and terminating it

   32 21 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/ahmed/Desktop/scrap/AppFlatForRent.py
   32 21 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/ahmed/Desktop/scrap/AppForSale.py
   32 21 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/ahmed/Desktop/scrap/CommercialForSale$

Both methods above give this kind of error by terminating one of the program but when i run the program which is terminated while running concurrently, it runs fine.

***Note***

- I think there is something wrong with the way I am inserting data
- All the python programs are exactly same except that there are different webpage links for extracting data

Please help. I am trying to solve this problem from past 24 hours! help!!

Comment: How about using multiprocessing to run all the scripts in a dedicated process and schedule the multiprocessing script via cron job?

Comment: There is no error in the cronjob statement above. What evidence do you have that "VillaHouseForSale.py" doesn't run?

Comment: please see the edited question. it runs but with error as explained above

Comment: to make things easier: Can you produce a minimal example, that shows the same behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I propose using Multiprocessing to run scripts at the same time. Maybe you could even make the whole setup simpler, by not packing the the scripts in different programms and change only a simple variable like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
homepage_lis=[google, facebook, twitter]

def data_getter(homepage):
    do_something(homepage)  
    return (result_from_homepage)

def data_saver(result): 
    do_something_with(result) 

def apply_async_with_callback():
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
    for i in len(homepage_lis):
        pool.apply_async(data_getter, args = (homepage_lis[i]), callback = data_saver)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    apply_async_with_callback()
```

Tweak the process number according to the number of cores/threads you have availabe.